# Angular - how to display the initial name of a route after redirection

Tags: angular, angular-routing

Lets set a simple set of routes:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: 'app',              
    component: AppPage01Component
  },
  { path: 'not-found',
    component: NotFoundComponent
  },
  { path: 'root',  redirectTo: 'app',        pathMatch: 'full' },
  { path: '',      redirectTo: 'not-found',  pathMatch: 'full' },
  { path: '**',    redirectTo: 'not-found',  pathMatch: 'full' }
 ];
```

Now lets say somewhere in our program we have and object that references a route, e.g.

```
const item = {name: "A", route: "app"};
```

and in some component we have:

```
this.router.navigateByUrl(item.route);
```

This will take the user to component:  AppPage01Component.

... and, if there is some unknown route e.g:

```
const item = {name: "A", route: "XXX"};
```

The routing redirection of - path: '**' -will take the user to component:  NotFoundComponent

Here is the question. If redirected from an invalid route entry, how can we display the initial-invalid route "XXX" in the page of the NotFoundComponent ?

If I try:

```
constructor(private router: Router) { }

ngOnInit() {
  console.log(this.router.url)' // shows: /not-found
}
```

I get:  /not-found,

Is there a way I could get:  "XXX"  (the initial route that was redirected) ?

Answer (score 1):

You can do one thing in this scenario. You can add param to your routes `previousRoute` and send every time you navigate by URL. This way you can always get back the last URL which might be valid.

```
this.router.navigateByUrl(item.route, { queryParams: { prevRoute: this.router.url}};
```

Now, the question is how to check whether the current route is valid or not. You can use `router.url` and check if it includes the `not-found` path. When you are redirected to `not-found` route you can check the params and do whatever you want to.

You need to use ActivatedRoute and fetch the query params:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';

  constructor(
    private route: ActivatedRoute
  ) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    const filter = this.route.snapshot.queryParamMap.get('prevRoute');
    console.log(filter); // get the previous route
  }
```

There could be other ways to get this done. You can create a wrapper around your routerService and check when the router is trying to navigate it to the not-found. You can also use stack to maintain last few routing and check them.

Comment: This makes sense. Thx.

Comment: How about if user enters the path directly in the browser's address bar - e.g: http://localhost:4200/XXX , or we do not get the chance to update the .queryParams{...} ?

Comment: If such thing happens, it means the user is directly inputting the not found URL and will give undefined for the query param. So, if user navigate through any url before not-found, query param is always populated else it is undefined.

Comment: Does it help? If yes, please mark the answer as accepted for future references.